# append() in jquery not woring

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am new to jquery and ajax. I really need you help.

I have two select box, one dynamically add options to a select when the first select box is checked. I used ajax to dynamically get those values. I am getting values correctly from database. But when I try to append these options inside second select box it is not working.   My code is below

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
       
        $("#categories").change(function() {
            
            var categoryId = $("#categories").val();
            //alert(categoryId);
            if(categoryId == 2) {
                
                $.ajax({                    
                    url: "<?= base_url();?>Web/getRateType",
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        //alert(data[0].status);


                        $("#rate_container").css('display', 'block');
                        $("#expected_salary_container").css('display', 'none');
                        $("#rate_categories").empty();

                       // var str = '<label>Rate*</label></br>';
                        //str += '<select name="rate_categories" style="font-size:15px" id="rate_categories"><option value="0">Select</option>';
                        var str = '';
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            //alert(value['rate_id']);
                            str +='<option value="'+ value['rate_id'] +'">'+ value['rate_cat_name'] +'</option>';  
                        });
                       alert(str);
                        //str += '</select>';
                        var x = $("#rate_categories").append(str);
                        if(x){
                            alert(x);
                        }
                    }
                });//$("#rate_categories").append('<option value="'+ value.rate_id +'">'+ value.rate_cat_name +'</option>');
            }
            else if (categoryId == 1) {
                document.getElementById("expected_salary_container").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("rate_container").style.display = "none";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("expected_salary_container").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("rate_container").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Job Type*</label>
<select name="categories" id="categories">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<?php foreach($categories as $key => $value) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $value['type_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['cat_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Rate*</label>
    <select id="rate_categories" name="rate_categories">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here alert(x) is working fine. but the html is not appending inside select box. could anybody please help

jQuery is referenced in the header:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: how about `alert(str);` result ?

Comment: it is showing the option values corectly.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: just my guess try selector like this `$('select[name="rate_categories"]').append(str);`

Comment: console shows this errorUncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: why it is showing console error " Uncaught ReferenceError: $ " is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the ready function before the jQuery JavaScript is included. Reference jQuery first. However please check the network tab JS file load.

You should put the references to the jquery scripts first.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

Please use compatible new jquery CDN Url in above script tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solved it. I referenced jquery at header then it worked . thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the code below and see if that works for you. I've changed the vanilla JS to jQuery. You may need to re-insert your php code back in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Hide everything
  $("#expected_salary_container, #rate_container").hide();


  $("#categories").change(function() {

    var categoryId = $("#categories").val();
    console.log(categoryId);
    //alert(categoryId);
    if (categoryId == 2) {

      let data = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
      str = "";
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        //alert(value['rate_id']);
        str += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
        console.log(str);
      });
      var x = $("#rate_categories").append(str);

      $("#expected_salary_container").hide();
      $("#rate_container").show();

    } else if (categoryId == 1) {
      $("#expected_salary_container").show();
      $("#rate_container").hide();

    } else {
      $("#expected_salary_container").hide();
      $("#rate_container").show();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Job Type*</label>
    <select name="categories" id="categories">
      <option value="0">Select</option>

      <option value="2">Cat 1</option>
      <option value="1">Cat 2</option>
      <option value="2">Cat 3</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="rate_container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Rate*</label>
    <select id="rate_categories" name="rate_categories">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="expected_salary_container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Salary*</label>
    <select id="rate_categories" name="rate_categories">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```